# Dynamic Select Query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I want to run dynamic **SELECT** sql in oracle.

In Sql server it is simple

```
  declare @a int,@b int,@c int;

   set @a=1;
   set @b=2;
   set @c=3;

   drop table empl
   create table empl (id int,name nvarchar(100))
   insert into empl values (1,'name1'),(2,'name2'),(3,'name3'),(4,'name4'),(5,'name4')

  select * from empl
  where id=@a or id= @b or id=@c
```

**Result:**

```
1   name1
2   name2
3   name3
```

But when I try do this in oracle with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE i have issues that it is doesn't support select statement without into.

How I can Achieve this statement in Oracle ?

Comment: I freely confess my ignorance of TSQL, but what is the `SELECT` in your example meant to accomplish? It *looks* as though it's simply selecting the variables into themselves, if it does anything at all.

Comment: I want to use variables in select statement. And run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example using SQL Server syntax, all you are doing is **projecting** three values, `10`, `20` and `30`. I don't see anything **dynamic** in there.

```
SQL> SELECT 10 a, 20 b, 30 c FROM dual;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
        10         20         30
```

In **PL/SQL**, you just need to **declare the variables** and **assign the value**.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    a     NUMBER;
  3    b     NUMBER;
  4    c     NUMBER;
  5    var_a NUMBER;
  6    var_b NUMBER;
  7    var_c NUMBER;
  8  BEGIN
  9    a :=10;
 10    b := 20;
 11    c := 30;
 12    SELECT A,b,c INTO var_a, var_b, var_c FROM DUAL;
 13    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Values are '||var_a||' '||var_b||' '||var_c);
 14  END;
 15  /
Values are 10 20 30

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

**UPDATE** As per OP's updated question:

You don't need an explicit cursor, just use a **cursor for loop**.

For example, using the standard EMP table in SCOTT schema:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    a     NUMBER;
  3    b     NUMBER;
  4    c     NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6    a := 10;
  7    b := 20;
  8    c := 30;
  9    FOR i IN (SELECT empno FROM emp WHERE deptno IN (a, b, c))
 10    LOOP
 11    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee number is '||i.empno);
 12    END LOOP;
 13  END;
 14  /
Employee number is 7369
Employee number is 7499
Employee number is 7521
Employee number is 7566
Employee number is 7654
Employee number is 7698
Employee number is 7782
Employee number is 7788
Employee number is 7839
Employee number is 7844
Employee number is 7876
Employee number is 7900
Employee number is 7902
Employee number is 7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: My real query is more complex. And I want to declare variables in the begin of query. And do not change values in whole query

Comment: Then we'll need a better idea of what you want to accomplish. Your sample code doesn't really do anything.

Comment: @VitalyAscheulov Added an example of PL/SQL. But, all that I did is assignthe values to the variables, and then SELECT INTO other variables. if there is something different that you want, then please elaborate.

Comment: It is ok when if it is 1 value. I corrected my tsql code. Is there solution will be cursor now ?

Comment: This variant is displayed data like text. Is there any way to display data like table ? The same if we run select query in Oracle SQL Developer.  (http://postimg.org/image/y51ht3n1x/)

Comment: @VitalyAscheulov Yes, it is simple using **substitution variables**. Try `SELECT &a a, &b b, &c c FROM dual;` and put enter the values when prompted.